# Problem saving excel file after inserting data

Tags: c#, excel

I want to write data to an existing excel file ( I do it easily )
But I can not save the changes on the excel file ( actually I see the changes on the excel file, but it seems opened and after all it occurs some problems such as "the file is already opened with same name and so on ... )

```
Excel.Application app= new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook appbook= app.Workbooks.Open(appxls, 0, true, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, false, 0, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        Excel.Sheets pages= appbook.Worksheets;
        Excel.Worksheet page= (Excel.Worksheet)pages.get_Item(1);
```

//... i change some values on the excel file and want to save them :
// appxls is a string holding the path

```
 appbook.SaveAs(appxls, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,false, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    appbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    app.Quit();
```

Where is the problem, how can I solve it using Microsoft.interop.

Answer (score 3):

You are opening the workbook using the file name named 'appxls' as read-only. (The `ReadOnly` parameter of the `Workbooks.Open` method is the third parameter, and you are passing in `true`.)

You are later using the `Workbook.SaveAs` method, but are attempting to save the file using the same exact file name held by your 'appxls' variable that you used to open the workbook. This is an attempt to overwrite the read-only file that you have open, and, therefore, is prevented.

I can see two possible solutions:

1. Pass in `false` for the `ReadOnly` parameter of the `Workbooks.Open` method so that you can save it later using  `Workbook.Save` method. In your case, you could save it by calling `appbook.Save()`.
2. Continue to open the file as read-only, but when you later use the `Workbook.SaveAs` method, you should save it under a *different* name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks ! that's work with that problem:

I go the location where the excel file is saved, and I open the excel file and the file freezes :(

Comment: the save does not work completely too. old data would be deleted :(

Comment: Ok, sorry, in my original answer, I missed that you were opening the file on a read-only basis. So there are actually two issues to deal with here. See my updated answer, above...

Comment: thanks again, but really save do not work safely :( I can not find why. I can not hold the old information. I insert something and the old information dissappears :(

Comment: You should show your new code now and show the code that makes the changes. Also, tell us which is happening: is the Save or SaveAs method throwing an exception, or is Save/SaveAs running cleanly, but the file is not showing any saved changes when you re-open the same file. Lastly, are you running this on a server where multiple Excel instances might be present at the same time?

Comment: i'm running this on my own computer. Either I will post soon again my new code. Actually I'm trying to do it with Oledb now, cause of unsuccessful operation using mic.interop

Answer (score -1):

I've tried to use Oledb and was succesful with creating any empty excel file with the code:

```
    OleDbConnection connection= new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
    string addSheet= "CREATE TABLE Mus(id nvarchar(255), name nvarchar(5))";
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand sqlcommand = new OleDbCommand(addSheet,connection);
    sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
```

where connectionstring is :

```
string connectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\myexcel.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";
```

So I have another proble with adding with inserting and the mistake is :

"number of query values and destination fields are not the same"

I wrote my command carefully, and I can not find the mistake :( How can I solve it?

Thanks !

(it's important I'm working on aspx, the code above works at desktop applications, but for aspx save location should be different like responce.outstream as I have understood from my researches)

Comment: I solved my problem, sorry :( my items at insert command and items by inserting were different.