# Getting error on calling SaveAs method

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm trying to create a csv file from an excel file using MS Excel Interop in my C#/Winforms app.

Am getting this error on SaveAs method in the code below.

> 'The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:
>
> • Make sure the specified folder exists.  • Make sure the folder that
>   contains the file is not read-only.  • Make sure the file name does
>   not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  | or 
>   *  • Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218
>   characters.'z

I tried setting readonly to false in Workbook's Open(...)  method as per:
[Problem saving excel file after inserting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574722/problem-saving-excel-file-after-inserting-data) , but still getting the same error.

In my code, the csv file path was:C:\
If I change the csv file path to C:\SomeFolder or some shared UNC path, then I dont get this error.

Please advise.COuld there be some permissions issues with C drive?

Heres the code:

```
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); 
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
xlApp.Visible = false; 
wbkSrc = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(m_sSrcFil, 
                        Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


                wstSrc = (Worksheet)wbkSrc.Worksheets[sSrcSht]; 
                //wstSrc.Activate();

                rngWork = wstSrc.Cells.get_Range("H:H", System.Reflection.Missing.Value); 
                rngWork.NumberFormat = "General";

                dteTmpDate = Convert.ToDateTime(m_sBusDate); 
                sTmpFileName = m_sSrcFil.Substring(0, m_sSrcFil.IndexOf(".")) + "_" + 
                    m_sUserName + "_" + dteTmpDate.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd") + ".Csv";

                wstSrc.SaveAs(sTmpFileName, XlFileFormat.xlCSV, Type.Missing, 
                    Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Sounds like folder permissions issue

Comment: Hi David,thanks for your inputs.The file name is:"22010_Sep11TestReport_rtsim36_2011_09_30.Csv". This file name being the same,if change csv file path to some other path like C:\SomeFolder,then I dont get this error and csv file gets saved on the machine.So,looks like the problem is not with the file name itself although the error message seems to suggest that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly `sTmpFileName` is an invalid path. The error message tells you that. Perhaps `m_sUserName` contains characters that are not allowed. Perhaps it is a `DOMAIN\USER` format user name. Perhaps the file name really is too long. Or perhaps something else is up. Take a look at the actual value of  `sTmpFileName` and you will have your explanation.

---

As an aside, your code is mistaken in using `SubString` and `IndexOf(".")` to get the filename without the extension.  Filenames can have multiple periods in them. The extension is simply that text after the *final* period. Consider these file names and how your code will deal with them:

```
C:\My.Folder.Name\TheFile.xls
C:\MyFolder\TheFile.Name.xls
```

Instead you should use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx).

Comment: David, please see my comments against your question above.Thanks.

Comment: What's the filename including the full path? Are you using relative paths?

Answer (score 1):

Excel SaveAs is quite picky. Things like `c:\folder\\file.csv` (note the double backslash) are accepted by File.Exists or when you open a workbook, but not when saving

Answer (score 0):

Check your FilePath where you are saving if it is more than 218 characters then also you will get this error.